# Is a magnetic field affected by the presence of air?

Tags: electromagnetism, magnetic-fields, home-experiment

Does air affect a magnetic field's ability to attract ferromagnets?
If a magnetic field and a ferromagnet were placed in a vacuum would there be a better performance?

Comment: The magnetic permeability of air is negligibly different than vacuum, so probably not.

Comment: @DumpsterDoofus please explain this a bit more.

Answer (score 1):

The configuration of a static magnetic field coming from a source object like a bar magnet is determined by the [constitutive relations](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Constitutive_equation#Constitutive_equations_in_electromagnetism_and_related_areas) of the surrounding material, and in particular the magnetic permeability determines how the field lines act.

In the first case, you have a field emanating from a magnet, traveling through air ($\mu_r=1.000000349)$, and entering a ferrous material ($\mu_r\approx4000$).

In the second case, you have a field emanating from a magnet, traveling through vacuum ($\mu_r=1)$, and entering a ferrous material ($\mu_r\approx4000$).

The two situations are nearly identical, so there will be no change in performance.

Answer (score 1):

Oxygen in air is a triplet diradical, ↑O-O↑, a a paramagnet. Its slightly greater magnetic permeability than vacuum would slightly concentrate the field.  Compare magnetic susceptibilties,

Nitrogen (1 atm) $-0.5\times 10^{-8}$ 
Oxygen (1 atm)  $209.0\times 10^{-8}$

[image]